# Create a result based on comparing 2 Dataframes in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 data frames, DF1 and DF2.

DF1 = ['IDS'] ['DateTime']
DF2 = ['IDS'] ['Deadline']

IDS are STR and the others are DateTime.

I want to add a column to DF1 called ['Late']

My code is

```
DF1['Late'] = DF1.where(DF1['IDS']==DF2['IDS'] and DF1['DateTime'] > DF2['Deadline'], "Late","Not Late")
```

I get the following: 
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

So I made a new Columns in DF1 called ['Deadline']

```
DF1['Late'] = DF1.where(DF1['IDS']==DF2['IDS'] and DF1['Deadline'] > DF2['Deadline'], "Late","Not Late")
```

But i get the same error?

Thanks,

Comment: wrap your conditions with parenthesis and use `&` instead of `and`. However your error seems to be cause `df1` and `df2` have different indexes

Comment: I did not set an Index on either, so they just count rows 1 - x, DF1 is about 300 rows while DF2 is about 6000. 
I'll do the wrap and &, thanks, :-)

Comment: how do you expect to compare a 300-sized series of IDs to a 6000-sized?

Comment: because no 2 datasets are ever the same size. While I am new to Python, data analysis via SQL, Tableau, VBA etc.. is not new to me, often you will have tables with differing volumes and you create a join (left or inner) on the matching IDs, Maybe I need to do that with Pandas, I am not sure if that's even possible as I am still very new.